# Check if there is an image in the ressources of a page

Tags: menu, typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript

I've got a serie of page and shortcut in a sysfolder.
With those page, I build a list of links.

You can add an image for each links by adding an image in the ressources in the page properties.

Everythings work perfectly except for page without image.
If so, the links, is show twice.

I need to add a condition to not execute the `before.cObject` things if there no image in the ressources.
This is were I need your help.

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
    special = directory
    special.value = {$lib.sysfolder}

    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO {
            allWrap  = <li>|</li>
            ATagTitle.field = subtitle // title

            before.cObject = IMAGE
            before.cObject.file.import = uploads/media/
            before.cObject.file.import.field = media
            before.cObject.file.import.listNum = 0
            before.cObject.altText.field = abstract
            before.cObject.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = uid
        }
        ACT = 0
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the generated HTML. It's a liste with three items.
The first and third one havn't got any image. The second got one.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="mobile/">Mobile</a><a href="mobile/" title="Mobile" onfocus="blurLink(this);">Mobile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="actualite/flux-rss-et-reseaux-sociaux/"><img src="uploads/media/feed.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Icône de flux RSS"></a><a href="actualite/flux-rss-et-reseaux-sociaux/" title="RSS" onfocus="blurLink(this);">RSS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contact/">Contact</a><a href="contact/" title="Contact" onfocus="blurLink(this);">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly use

before.cObject = IMAGE

use a COA:

```
before.cObject = COA
before.cObject {
   stdWrap.if {
     isTrue.field = media
   }
   10 = IMAGE
   10 ...
}
```

and you so put the "if.isTrue" on the COA